# Struts2-core-6.1.1 with Content-Security-Policy HTTP header

Tags: unsafe-inline, script-src

I'm migrating a **struts2-core-2.5.30** project to **struts2-core-6.1.1**, however I was getting the following error:

Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-YGAaDo9iR3Nd5TXLz6HiMO6v' 'strict-dynamic' http: https:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-...'), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution. Note that hashes do not apply to event handlers, style attributes and javascript: navigations unless the 'unsafe-hashes' keyword is present.

I already placed in the  of the jsp that I use the security policy for the content

```
 <meta http-equiv=content-type" content="script-src 'unsafe-inline'; script-src-elem 'http://localhost:8080/My_App/html/js/file.js'; text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" />
```

And I get the following error:

Refused to load the script 'http://localhost:8080/My_App/html/js/file.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'nonce-7yiWsJW8gTw1QSsMQ-u_Ph61' 'strict-dynamic' http: https:". Note that 'strict-dynamic' is present, so host-based allowlisting is disabled. Note that 'script-src-elem' was not explicitly set, so 'script-src' is used as a fallback.
What am I doing wrong?

I want to clarify that in the version of struts that I had before, this error did not appear.

Answer (score 0):

Struts 6 added a [CSPInterceptor](https://struts.staged.apache.org/core-developers/csp-interceptor) that is in the default stack. I have had great difficulty finding much information about it, but using the `<s:script>` or `<s:link>` tag injects the nonce value automatically, which is rather nice. I do wish there were better documentation.

I believe it is possible to completely disable individual interceptors, or to create your own stack that does not include this one.